# jquery autocomplete json file key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a working autocomplete field with a JSON source file. Now I want to change the JSON to a key value format. Like this

```
{"Countries":{"Andorra":"AD","United Arab Emirates":"AE"}}
```

How do I have the field store the "AD" and autocomplete "Andorra"?

```
$(function () {

$.get('../data/data.json', function (data) {

    var country = Object.keys(data['Countries']).map(function (k) {
        return data['Countries'][k]
    });

    $('#country_autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: country,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.key);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Where do you store the value?

Comment: You can use the transformResult property of the autocomplete .

Comment: var Countries = '{"Countries":{"Andorra":"AD","United Arab Emirates":"AE"}}'; 
var result = JSON.parse(Countries);
var NewCountries={
     Countries: swapCountriesCode(result.Countries)
};

console.log(NewCountries);
function swapCountriesCode(jsonObj){
  var result = {};
  for(var key in jsonObj){
    result[jsonObj[key]] = key;
  }
  return result;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here , I have converted the JSON response to the one as needed by the autocomplete ;

```
var data = {"Countries":{"Andorra":"AD","United Arab Emirates":"AE" , "India" : "IN" , "Australia" : "AUS"} } ;

var countries = [] ;

var country_full_names = new Array();
country_full_names =   Object.keys(data.Countries);

country_full_names.forEach( function( element  ){
    var obj = {};
    obj.value = element ;
    obj.data = data.Countries[element] ;
    console.log(obj);
    countries.push(obj);
});




$('#country_autocomplete').autocomplete({
  lookup: countries,
 onSelect: function (suggestion) {
       alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

In the above snippet I have initialized the data without AJAX/XHR 
. But to init with the request   just   replace the first line with this

```
var data = {};
$.get('../data/data.json', function ( response ) {
 data = response ;
 });
```

Here is the working fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/u77va6xt/

Comment: How do I have the `data` passed to request? I want something like this `<option value="AD"> Andorra </option>` But not dropdown but autocomplete. Is it possible?

Comment: The suggestions show based on what you type in the text . I am a little confused as what you need exactly . Are you saying you want to populate the server for json response based on the input in the textbox ??

Comment: Yes. The user type in the full country name. But I want the form to submit the country code.

Comment: I think you should use select2 then

Comment: Here is the select2 link https://select2.github.io/examples.html . I think its what you actually need .It will give you the optino to show text for value .